# How to install 'qiskit' in pyodide or jupyter-lite in backend?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pyodide

According to [jupyter-lite doc](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/python/packages.html#bundling-additional-packages-by-default) pyodide is used to add packages default in jupyter-lite.

I need help in creating module and I didn't understand how to create and use that in jupyter-lite.

Also if I use

```py
import piplite 
await piplite.install(["qiskit"])
```

it gives me an error

`ValueError: Couldn't find a pure Python 3 wheel for 'qiskit-terra<0.8,>=0.7'. You can use micropip.install(..., keep_going=True) to get a list of all packages with missing wheels.`

Comment: Have you consulted the documentation on building a Python wheel package? Start with this guide: https://realpython.com/python-wheels/#what-is-a-python-wheel

Comment: @JohnHanley I tried and create a wheel alao create a meta.yaml file but stuck at pyodide build. How can build for qiskit using pyodide-build package in python. In the package the file run for building package `buildpkg` is looking for Makefile.envs.

Comment: Why are you doing a Pyodide build? Building a wheel is independent of Pyodide.

Comment: @JohnHanley ok I want to add qiskit (quantum computing module) in jupyter-lite (light weight webassembly jupyter notebook)  jupyter notebook didn't contain qiskit module default and I can add this using pyodide which is shown in [jupyter-lite doc](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/python/packages.html#bundling-additional-packages-by-default)